# Calling rails_asset_id directly in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to call the private function rails_asset_id (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/rails_asset_id) to generate a cache-busting key?

I need the same functionality for files that I'll be pulling down from an ajax request (so I can't just use the built in *_include_tag functions) that I want to be cached until they are modified. Is there a way to call rails_asset_id directly so that I don't have to re-implement the modified time checks and caching it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `send` to call private methods. For the file timestamp to work properly, [`rails_asset_id`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.6/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L787) requires the asset file to be inside `assets_dir`, which is by default the `/public` directory. Here's an example:

```
# Get asset id for the file /public/json/example.json
send(:rails_asset_id, 'json/example.json')
```

If you're using it outside view, this is one way to do it.

```
require 'action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper'
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
send(:rails_asset_id, 'json/example.json')
```

Note that all of these techniques are hackish and will not work on future versions of Rails since they have changed the way the asset tag helpers are organized. So proceed with caution.

Comment: Is there a way to use this outside of a view? I actually pulled the needed functionality into a lib class and am obviously getting an undefined method error when using this there.

Comment: @ShyGuy: I've updated my answer with using it outside a view.